# Azure Storage : how to upload/add word document/csv into file share using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am newly working in Azure Storage account (so please be patient with me).

I have a requirement where I have to upload document (specifically .docx, .txt and .csv.

I created Azure storage account and added a file share to do so. Followed by, I have generated SAS token.

My storage account is publicly available and networking tab has All Networks selected.

Now, I made an attempt to upload my document using rest API, here is my postman code snippet

```
PUT /sharedname/subdir/BlobTesting.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net
x-ms-type: file
x-ms-file-permission: inherit
x-ms-file-attributes: ReadOnly
x-ms-file-creation-time: now
x-ms-file-last-write-time: now
x-ms-content-length: 102
Date: Wed, 08 Sep 2021 23:23:20 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey mystorageaccount: xxxxxxxx
x-ms-version: 2020-04-08
```

I am getting below error message

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
        <Message>Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header.
    RequestId:155df990-401a-007e-4d09-a5aba4000000
    Time:2021-09-08T23:31:50.5455929Z</Message>
    </Error>
```

Also, I wonder how am I going to upload the content of the file as well as from documentation I didnot find any specfic way to do so.

Could some one please help.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `Authorization` and `Date` headers if you're using shared access signature. Your request URL should be like `https://account.file.core.windows.net/sharedname/subdir/BlobTesting.txt?sastoken`. Can you retry by removing those two headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Please use below postman code snippet :

```
PUT https:// mystorageaccount.file.core.windows.net/ /sharedname/subdir/BlobTesting.txt?sastoken
Headers : 
x-ms-content-length : maximum size for the file in bytes
x-ms-type : file
x-ms-file-permission : inherit
x-ms-file-attributes : ReadOnly
x-ms-file-creation-time : now
x-ms-file-last-write-time : now
```

[image]

The file is successfully created in the Storage Account :

[image]

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file

Comment: I am getting this error

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code>
    <Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:107d60c2-201a-001a-1f5f-a55a3c000000
Time:2021-09-09T09:47:37.6854504Z</Message>
    <HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName>
    <HeaderValue>48</HeaderValue>
</Error>

Comment: Now I added one more header Content-Length with value as 0. I am getting below error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch</Code>
    <Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:88163754-501a-003f-1b60-a5f340000000
Time:2021-09-09T09:50:37.1005049Z</Message>
</Error>

Comment: Please use below header:
x-ms-content-length : 48
instead of content-length : 48

Comment: yes, I have added that and also added Content-Length with value as 0. Now the error message is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Error> <Code>AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch</Code> <Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type. RequestId:88163754-501a-003f-1b60-a5f340000000 Time:2021-09-09T09:50:37.1005049Z</Message>

Comment: Please remove Content-Length: 0 header and try

Comment: same error
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch</Code>
    <Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:16cd2f4c-a01a-0004-3560-a5b6e4000000
Time:2021-09-09T09:54:53.5034580Z</Message>
</Error>

Comment: Lets take this discussion to the chat room. Please join : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236934/room-for-ramaraoadapa-mt-and-2437850